# Moving a closed question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions, moderation

There's several older questions I just stumbled across, which at the time were closed as "not programming related", but should now be moved to SuperUser. How should these be dealt with?

Reopening then voting to close is rather slow, as it requires 10 votes (5 to reopen, 5 to close as "belongs on _____")

I've just flagged them as needs-moderator-attention, is this the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends in part on:

- whether the OP is still around, or whether they were 1-question-wonders
- whether the question is going to be constructive to the new site (especially without OP input)
- what answers do they have?

Moving things to MSO is probably a lot clearer / easier. But yes, *if appropriate* flagging can help here; perhaps more than voting, since the questions are old